# I need to anchor a standard where there is a one-inch hole in the drywall

Tags: repair, drywall, hole, anchor

While I was putting in anchors to hold a shelf standard I had one that didn't install right and I was left with a one-inch hole. Some kind of anchor or support absolutely has to go there. It's too small for me to go inserting a piece of lumber behind it (not a good place for it either) and I can't find an anchor that would hold to a hole that size.

Comment: *Why* is it not a good place for backing lumber? What kind of finish does the wall have? (A photo would help.) A drywall repair incorporating some backing seems like the right answer, but we don't have enough info.

Comment: Three problems with backing with wood:  have hand tremors and nowhere to brace my arm while I'm drilling or have anyone to help, it's in a corner and just a red hair off the side of the stud.

Comment: I cant comment yet due to no points, but i think the first posted answer is only considering the back side of the toggle bolt that is in deed often larger than 1 inch, but we must consider the front side as well which as OP points out is often less than one inch. What would commonly be done on the front side to span a gap (or for other various reasons) is to add a large washer, in this case larger than the inch your looking to cover. That said, the appropriate method would be to fix that hole properly and then relocate the hole

Comment: Do you have a drill and are you able to drill at an angle into the stud in the corner?

Answer (score 1):

There is a butterfly anchor sold at most hardware/home stores.  It's a V shape with a nut and a spring at the point of the V.  It will fit into a 1" hole and then expand once pushed through the hole to a wider diameter.  You may need to drill the diameter of the hole in the standard out to accommodate the larger screw.  But these are very strong drywall anchors.

Comment: I assume that you're referring to winged toggle bolts. The largest I have ever seen were made to span a half-inch. With a one-inch hole in the drywall, even if if spanned it wouldn't have much wall to hold onto. I'd have to support the standard while anchoring and that would be a three-handed job.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ways to play this. It depends on how much work you want to do

1. There's a wide variety of drywall anchors on the market beyond the toggle bolt. My suggestion is head to the big box store and buy the largest toggle-type you can get. The best solution here is what one calls a "driller toggle", where a large metal plate drills in, and then the screw forces that metal plate vertical. You might want to repair the drywall first, just so it can't wiggle.
2. Widen your hole (as in cut a larger opening) and put a 1 x 3 or 1 x 4 behind the hole. Let's say you cut a 4 inch square hole. Cut your board to 6". Take some drywall screws and screw it to the drywall on either side of the hole. Put your cut section back in, screw it to the board as well, then tape and mud it. Once your wall repair is complete you can screw the shelf  through the drywall and into to the board directly.